# Add fields and update array and scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-forms

I want to add some questions to my Google form but my response sheet has a script and an array, which do not like that.

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

The URL is the link for the form.

Here is the edit script:

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1g1RYJ25dBA_CB2pzL6CYQDq9WlcwGEeL_C8q0dYgxnY');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 10; 
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

And here is the Array:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), "19AM" & ROW( A2:A )-2 + 100000 ,""))
```

I want to add 2 questions to my form.

Here is what I get:

[image]

When I copy the Array formula into J2, this is what I get:

> #REF! Error  Array results could not be expanded because it would overwrite the data in J3

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the results could not be expanded because `J3` is not blank (empty). Also check that the cells below `J3` are blank too.

Regarding the script you should have to change the following code line

```
var urlCol = 10;
```

Just replace `10` by the column number to be used for the response urls.